# File Missing Error after creating exe file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, deployment, exe

I have created one windows application project and it works fine.While form loading , it reads one text file and prints data to table in the Form . When i published and executing it ,it throws file missing error.  Following that text file is missing when i converting project to executable file. That text file is present in the application's start path folder . Did i missed anything while publishing it ?

Error :
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\4V17NKV8.EJ8\H5VC3CZ8.AM3\atum..tion_5f39d67ebcfcae03_0001.0000_14487f1ba676fa3d\Data'.`

I'm using visual studio 2012 and c# project.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code where you try to load your text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this error . Actually i did the mistake in assigning file path . Previously i have assigned file path as following :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader"E:/123.txt");
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

so after creating executable file , when we running the executable file in some other system we should copy this txt file in the same folder (E:/123.txt). But thats not fair . But Using installer method we can embed the files, and if you dont want to create installer file and directly exe file means do the following .

1. Add the file by right clicking project name and select add existing file . It will add the file in the list.

2.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        string path;
        path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        path = path.Replace("file:\\", "");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path +"/123.txt");
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

you should add the namespace of `System.Reflection`.
3. Then Publish your project , it will deploy the file with your published data.